# Pub-Sub messaging system for two way communication

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, message-queue, publish-subscribe

[image: Pub-Sub Messaging System Overview]
Hi, I have the system as captured in the image. I'm planning to adopt a reliable messaging system, but I'm bit confused over which one to use. Below explained the detail flow of data and my requirement.

```
Step 1: data from System is given to Publisher. 
Step 2: Publisher simply pushes the data to the Topic based Messaging 
        system.
Step 3: There will be  more than one subscribers for each topic and
        subscribers should get notified as soon there are some entries in
        messaging system. 
Step 4: Subscribers process the data and update the status back to messaging 
        system. 
Step 5: Publisher should get notified for the processed messages and 
        acknowledge the System which gave the data.
```

So, my question is can I use RabbitMq or Kafka for "Topic Based Messaging System" ? my main requirement here is to update the status back from subscribers and also publisher should get notification for the status update. (I'm not much bothered about the throughput, performance, scalable AT THIS POINT of TIME). Also my another concern is data recovery/HA.

Comment: You see to be interested in Synchronous processing i.e. publisher waits for response. Typically queues are used in an architecture to achieve Async processing. There are ways to validate whether a transaction was processed or not without making the flow Synchronous, please clarify if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm looking for how publisher will know whether transaction is processed or no and I want that acknowledgement from the subscribers. No publisher is not synchronous here.

Comment: @Abhinay - Did you find a topic based MQ that provides this out of the box support or did you compromise with using different topics for acknowledgements from subscribers?

Comment: @AndyDufresne : there is no out of box support(but similar does exists in RabbitMQ). We went ahead with Rabbitmq. RabbitMQ has similar kind of getting notification back from subscribers and based on that publisher will decide to remove the message. However we haven't used this feature, we have modified our design.

Answer (score 2):

How about having a N+1 topic system, one for publishing messages which would be consumed by N subscribers, and N topics for acknowledgements, one per subscriber.
Your "System" could subscribe to all these N acknowledgment topics, and can verify if all the subscribers processed the original message which was published by the producer.
Each message in Kafka for eg. has a message key, and the same message key can be used to co-relate the original message with its subscriber specific acknowledgement.

Does this achieve what you want in your system ?